# Minimum syntax to guarantee no dynamic memory with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

Quite often I want to write higher order functional code like

```
void f(int value, const std::function<void(int)>& callback);

int x, y=5;
f(y, [&](int result) { x = result; });
```

In cases like these, I would like to be able to guarantee that the `std::function` constructor does not allocate any memory.  The guarantees in the spec are... hard to read.  There seems to be some guarantees surrounding `reference_wrapper`, but I have not been able to get them to work cleanly, due to what I think are lvalue vs rvalue issues.  I end up with

```
auto callback = [&](int result) { x = result; };
f(y, std::ref(callback));
```

In many of these cases, I want to leverage virtual functions, so I can't just template these issues away (although I have played with using a wrapper that accepts the lambda type as an argument, and wraps it with `std::ref`, sidestepping any issues regarding temporaries)

What is the minimum amount of syntactic boilerplate needed to ensure this pattern does not allocate any memory?

Comment: How about simply making `f()` be a template function and not use `std::function` at all? `template <typename Callable> void f(int value, Callable callback) { ... callback(...); ... }`

Comment: Agree with @Remy. The cases where you definitely do need a `std::function` instead of such a template are those cases where `f` needs to keep a copy of `callback` around until some async thing happens much later. That in turn means the reference to `y` would have a lifetime issue, and you'd want a `std::shared_ptr` and thus dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @MSalters or, simply those cases where `f()` can't be templated.

Comment: I think your best option, given the mess that is memory allocation and std::function.. is simply to write your own version of std::function, that uses an internal buffer, and throws if the object it holds is too large for the buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would work great if I could have templated virtual functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no guarantees of allocations (or lack of thereof) specified in the standard for `std::function` constructors. Most you can hope for is a recommendation, from 20.14.17.3.2:

> Recommended practice: Implementations should avoid the use of
> dynamically allocated memory for small callable objects, for example,
> where f refers to an object holding only a pointer or reference to an
> object and a member function pointer.

So your best bet would be to look at your implementation and check when allocation does not happen.

Comment: You might find this of interest. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/uses_allocator

Comment: Wow, Cppreference says that it guaranteed small object optimization for reference_wrapper.  But now that I look harder, I don't find that anywhere in the spec.  Serves me right for trusting them!

Comment: @Tiger4Hire's answer is valid until Cpp17. Is there a way to check that in Cpp20?